# Is one faster than another? func() or module.func()

Tags: python, import, call

I see that `from x import *` is discouraged all over the place.  Corrupts naming space, etc.

So I'm inclined to use `from . import x`, and when I need to use the functions, I'll call `x.func()` instead of just using `func()`.

The speed difference is probably very little, but I still want to know how much it might impact the performance?  So that I can keep the good habit without needing to worry about other things.

Comment: "The speed difference is probably very little, but I still want to know how much it might impact the performance?" - very little.

Comment: Don't worry about it until you have a performance issue.  Then you can run your code through a profiler and find out where the bottlenecks are.  Most of the time you won't have any issues.  The times that you do are unlikely to be caused by using `module.func()` over `func()` unless it's being called at the most critical point in your code.  And even then it probably won't be the issue.

Comment: `func()` translates to 1 name lookup and 1 function call.  `module.func()` translates into 2 name lookups and 1 function call.  That extra name lookup isn't going to cost you, but if you're worried about it you can do `from module import func`.  Then you've only import one name from `module`.  Another option is to assign the function to a local name before it gets used repeatedly in a loop.  `func = module.func`, then `for x in range(large_num):func()`

Comment: You could still do `from x import func` and have the best from both worlds…?

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski  Thank you very much.  And thank everyone else who helped to make sure.

Comment: @poke, Yes, there are many functions I'd like to use inside x.  Which make more sense to simply import it as a whole or import everything inside it.  But if I can spend time typing the imports everytime I needed something, I'd use what you suggested.

Comment: `from module import func1, func2, func3`

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski, 3 functions are okay.  Hundreds of them won't be a good trade off...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has practically no impact:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('math.pow(1, 1)', 'import math')
0.20310196322982677
>>> timeit.timeit('pow(1, 1)', 'from math import pow')
0.19039931574786806
```

Note I picked a function that would have very little run time so that any difference would be magnified.

Comment: Didn't anticipate so much response in such a short time.  But thanks. : )